# Get querystring value

Tags: c#, query-string, httpcontext

I want to make a method in my tools library that request the querystring from the url.
I created the following code, but i can't use the HttpContext in a class library.

```
    public string RequestString(string requestParam, string Default)
    {
        string param = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[requestParam];
        if (param != null)
        {
            return param;
        }
        else
        {
            return Default;
        }
    }
```

I know it is possible, but i can't remember how...

Comment: Do you have access to the URL?  Also, you can use `HttpContext.Current` from a class library, only it will be `null` when you're not in a a web request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Web.dll` assembly in your class library project.

But of course you will only be able to access the query string when your method is called in the context of a HTTP request.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) for more information about the HttpContext class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already added System.Web.Dll to the references but only in the wrong project... That's why it didn't work.. Maby i need to take a small break. Haha!  Thanks again :)